# Is $_SERVER['QUERY_STRING'] safe from XSS?

Tags: php, http, xss

I need to construct a form who's action takes you back to the exact same page - GET parameters included.  I'm thinking I can say something to the effect of:

```
echo '<form action="'.$_SERVER['SCRIPT_NAME'].'?'.$_SERVER['QUERY_STRING'].
     '" method="post">'
```

This seems to work, and testing passing a couple XSS attacks seems to be successful, as the output of QUERY_STRING seems to be URL encoded.  However the [PHP documentation](http://www.php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.server.php) does not mention this, so I'm not confident I can trust this behavior.

Is it safe to use QUERY_STRING the way I am above?  If not, what can I do instead?  References to documentation would be appreciated.

**Update** switched to SCRIPT_NAME, just mixed up which one was ok and which was bad in my head, thanks for catching me.  `action=""` does resolve my specific issue nicely, but I'm still curious if QUERY_STRING is pre-processed so it is safe to use or not, since there are other times you might want to re-use the query string, assuming it's safe to do so.

Comment: Never assume. You never know what those crooks can come up with!

Comment: Of course not :) that's the raw values from the uri

Comment: if you want to submit user back to same page, you do not even need to specify which action ...

Comment: Why not just leave the form action in blank? This will send a post to the same page, including the querystring.

Comment: You do know `PHP_SELF` itself is vulnerable, right? As the above comments say it's better to leave the action blank.

Comment: Making `action` blank doesn't mean that you're safe from assumed XSS attacks, but it gives you the same behavior.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You should never trust $_SERVER['QUERY_STRING'] as it can be used for XSS attacks.

In your case, one could exploit the vulnerability with:

```
http://your.server.com/your_script.php?"><script>alert(111);</script>
```

Note that the code above works on IE; FireFox and Chrome efficiently encode the query string before sending it to the web server.

I would always wrap it with [htmlentities](http://php.net/manual/en/function.htmlentities.php) (mind the double_encode parameter) as with every user input.

Good luck!

Comment: Thank you, /this/ is what I was asking.  We cannot trust the variable because it's contents are browser dependent, excellent.

Comment: +1 Please note the important piece of info. It's not that you cannot *use* the data; it's only that you cannot *trust* it :)

Answer (score 1):

First of all, you can not trust $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'] ([1](http://www.mc2design.com/blog/article/serverphp_self-can-not-be-trusted-but-there-are-safe-alternatives)) - use $_SERVER['SCRIPT_NAME'] instead.

As for $_SERVER['QUERY_STRING'], you should treat it as any other user input. Filter it before using it in your output. I would not recommend some sort of a general filter in this case. It would be better to reassemble the query string from specific pieces you expect to be there.

Answer (score 1):

If it's exploitable by XSS, first you need to know which attack. In the code posted here there is just one [simple attack](http://www.html-form-guide.com/php-form/php-form-action-self.html) using the PHP_SELF.

But, to avoid any problem you could just leave the form action in blank. This will send the form to the same page including the query string.

Answer (score 1):

This is another one of those instances where using PHPs `filter_input` is the way to go. My IDE NetBeans (hate it or love it) always complains whenever I open code that accesses `$_POST`, `$_GET`, `$_SERVER` and `$_COOKIE` directly without going through `filter_input`.

This is because of the reasons stated above - you're saying that you trust external data, when, if it can entered or manipulated by users, you cannot.

```
filter_input(INPUT_POST, 'id', FILTER_SANITIZE_NUMBER_INT);
filter_input(INPUT_SERVER, 'QUERY_STRING', FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING);
```

Read more [here](http://php.net/manual/en/function.filter-input.php)

Answer (score 0):

I can't think of any attacks that would work off-hand, but `PHP_SELF` itself is vulnerable and you're using `QUERY_STRING` without any filtering whatsoever, which seems odd.

Why not just leave the `action` parameter blank and let the browser decide? You can use Javascript to properly enforce this behaviour on the client-side if you want to be doubly sure.