# Keeping URL parameters during PHP redirect

Tags: php, html

This isn't working:

```
<?php
header('Location: www.mysite.com/index.php?foo=bar&var=abc');
?>
```

I end up with www.mysite.com/index.php?foo=bar I think HTML might be trying to interpret the &var as a character.  The initial variable is passed (after ?) but all subsequent are not (after &).

Comment: According to the HTTP specifications, Location headers must include a complete URL.  This is a bit of a wild guess, but try adding http:// at the front.  Aside from that, maybe post more code?

Comment: Can you post your actual code then?  And have you tried echoing out the string being passed to header()?  It's possible that the string is not what you think it is.  The example above looks valid and would retain both foo and var.

Comment: write them like `&amp;`. i.e write `&amp;` instead of `&`

Comment: err scratch that.. it is only for HTML sorry :(

Comment: Have you tried replacing `&` with `&amp;`?  Just a wild guess. Edit:  Seems Achshar got there before me!

Comment: I've just used a <meta> tag instead, it's done the trick!

Comment: header('Location: '.$_SERVER['SERVER_NAME'].'/index.php?'.$_SERVER['QUERY_STRING']);

Comment: @Nammari http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4581837/is-serverquery-string-safe-from-xss

and jdborg you should probably add that as an answer then or close the question :O

Comment: Ah, worked a treat Nammari!  Put it as the answer please.

Comment: with proper parsing/escaping please.. ^^

Comment: @Achshar I'm using it for an intranet so all good

Comment: @jdborg hmm but remember you are not the only one who will be seeing the answer. People look up for answers here and someone can use the unsafe code (which is secure for you but you are an exception)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
if( isset($_SERVER['HTTPS'] ) ) {
  header('Location: https://'.$_SERVER['SERVER_NAME'].'/index.php?'.$_SERVER['QUERY_STRING']);
}
else{
  header('Location: http://'.$_SERVER['SERVER_NAME'].'/index.php?'.$_SERVER['QUERY_STRING']);
}
```

<del>use [htmlspecialchars](http://php.net/manual/en/function.htmlspecialchars.php) to prevent html injection</del>

Comment: i am saying this again, that kind of code is unsafe. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4581837/is-serverquery-string-safe-from-xss

Comment: htmlspecialchars has no meaning to a header...  HTML escaping only makes sense in the realm of HTML.  Additionally, as I mentioned earlier, it is incorrect to not have the http:// at the front (or https://).  Omission is incorrect by the HTTP standards.

Comment: I know it seems like I'm being picky, but it seems that 90% of every header I see is wrong these days and it's really begun to annoy me.  The Location header will now be correct, however your htmlspecialchars advice is still completely incorrect.  A URL has no concept of HTML.  Only HTML has a concept of HTML (as silly as that sounds).  & is supposed to be & in a URL, not &amp;.  HTML escaping a URL in a HTML context is correct.  Doing it in a header context is wrong.

Comment: @Achshar: the question you link is about injecting raw user input in the site's HTML. I can't see how it applies to HTTP headers.

Comment: how about something on the lines of `url'); ?><script></script> <?php` as the query string? not sure though, don't have a server set up so cant test :(

Comment: Nothing ensures that the query string is ever output though.  URLs should be html escaped when being printed in an html document, not when being used as URLs.  As I said before, HTML has no meaning in a URL; HTML only has meaning in HTML.  Would you escape HTML for a mp3 document?  No.  HTML and HTTP are not explicitly linked.

Answer (score 0):

I was testing that case with this:

```
    <?php
    if (isset($_GET['foo']) ) { 
        echo '<pre>';
        print_r($_GET);
        echo '</pre>';
        exit(); 
    }
    $fp='http://server/header.php?foo=bar&var=abc';
    header("Location: ".$fp);
    exit();
    ?>
```

I call the address: http://server/header.php
and the redirect works fine to '**http://server/header.php?foo=bar&var=abc**' and the _GET is complete:

```
Array
(
    [foo] => bar
    [var] => abc
)
```

Notice:

1. location with first letter as capital letter.

   the colon and space after "Location"

   the full link

   the exit() call.

On the other hand, make sure that nothing is outputed to the browser BEFORE THE REDIRECT EXECUTES.

Comment: I can't make any sense of this.

Answer (score 0):

Redirecting index.php to hompage. same can be used for any other page redirection.

```
$url = str_replace('/index.php', '/', $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']);
header('Location: '. $url, true,302);
exit();
```